# Electric water heater making a squeaking noise

Tags: water-heater, squeak

I just moved into a new a new apartment a month ago (newly renovated) and the electric water heater (I think it's him, not 100% sure) is making a squeaking noise. I talked to the electrician and he claims it is normal. The noise isn't constant, it is happening 2-3 times a day for about 20 minutes. In those 20 minutes you hear the squeaking every about ten seconds. You can see it in the video. The sound strangely also exists when the heater is turned off (powered off the electricity). Anyone knows how to fix it?

Here's the video of the behaviour.
https://youtu.be/pEPRzM9ME0Y

Comment: wow, thanks for the video, i wish each question had one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As water gets hot inside the boiler the excess volume needs to be released. This is done with a pressure relief valve. That might be the squeaking you hear. If you also hear the squaking when the power is off the pressure relief valve can also be activated when the pressure in the piping suddenly increases. This could happend when a valve is closed fast.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Have the valve replaced

Comment: Ok thank you, I will talk to my hydraulic engineer.